# Azure: Upgrading to Azure SDK v2.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sdk-.net

We just upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 and installed the Azure 2.1 SDK.  When we opened our Azure project in VS 2012 it upgraded the Azure project to use the 2.1 version (from 1.6) but the ASP.Net MVC project and other class library projects that utilize the SDK as well did not have any of their references changed to use the new libraries.  They all still point to the 1.6 bits.  Is there a way to upgrade all references to libraries used to the 2.1 SDK?  We have references to Windows Azure Storage Clients, Caching Clients, Diagnostics etc and I'm afraid we will miss something just removing old references and adding new ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not recommend blindly updating the libraries as there have been significant changes.

Storage client library 2.0 (which is part of SDK 2.1) is drastically different (though much better IMHO) from previous versions. There have been namespace changes, some methods were removed.

Diagnostics libraries in SDK 2.1 have a dependency on Storage Client library 2.0. Again, I would not recommend upgrading that either.

My recommendation would be to evaluate the impact of upgrading libraries from 1.6 to 2.0. Please go through the following blog posts by storage team:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/introducing-windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-for-net-and-windows-runtime.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-breaking-changes-amp-migration-guide.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/06/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive.aspx

I also wrote a series of blog posts on upgrading code to 2.0 version which you can read here:

http://gauravmantri.com/2012/11/17/storage-client-library-2-0-migrating-table-storage-code/

http://gauravmantri.com/2012/11/24/storage-client-library-2-0-migrating-queue-storage-code/

http://gauravmantri.com/2012/11/28/storage-client-library-2-0-migrating-blob-storage-code/

http://gauravmantri.com/2012/12/26/storage-client-library-2-0-exception-handling/

http://gauravmantri.com/2012/12/30/storage-client-library-2-0-implementing-retry-policies/

Comment: @Guarav This is great info on the impact of the storage client libraries. Assuming the updating the storage client libraries what done independently. What would you consider to be the rest of the steps the OP should take?

Comment: @DennisBurton IMO, updating storage client libraries is a big ticket item. Once it is done, all others are pretty simple. Diagnostics library in 2.1 does not involve any code changes from the previous one. Last remaining thing would be caching. With caching only thing to remember is that caching library 2.1 will only work with SDK 2.1. Needless to say, some heavy duty testing is required :). This blog may also be useful: http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/07/13/rebranding-part-2-and-upgrading-to-azure-sdk-2-0/

Comment: @GauravMantri We are using the old shared azure cache that is going to be discontinued next year to store session variables. If we upgrade to the latest caching libraries will that break our session use?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't worked on shared caching thus I can't really comment on this. Since the caching engine uses storage for some management, the thing you would need to see the dependency of latest caching library on storage client library. If it depends on the latest version, then it might create some problems. Again the best way to find that out is by giving it a try. HTH.